# Upload CSV coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, csv

[image]

I was trying to upload the CSV file into QGIS and somehow it doesn't read in the proper coordinate system EPSG:4326, WGS 84

Do you know what it might be the problem?? In a random exercise I tried EPSG:3857, WGS 84 pseudo mercador and the dots show up however in a completely area of the world and the point spread is rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of how you're importing the CSV into QGIS? 90 degree rotation is usually due to flipping lat/long.

Comment: Got it! Now it works! I thought the Latitude would be for the X coordinates.. but apparently it was for the Y. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/129406)

Comment: If you are a geographer and understand what lat and long are, but are unfamiliar with the mathematical notation of X and Y and can't remember which is which, then use the words of my maths teacher from 40 years ago which I've never forgotten: "X is a cross" ("across"). Not sure if he also told us to "wise up" (Y's up)...

Answer (score 2):

A CSV has no SRS information. When you load it in QGIS, it loads in some default SRS (usually 4326, but can vary). You can change your SRS by right-clicking the layer -> Properties -> General, and choose your source SRS there.

What may be happening:

- you loaded the CSV, but it has the wrong SRS; change it to the correct one.
- your loaded points are in the right SRS, but the coordinates showing on the screen are wrong; check if the project's SRS is different, and if on-the-fly projection is turned on.
- your loaded points are in the right SRS, but don't show together with other layers (and it should); check if the project has on-the-fly projection turned on, and all layers are in their correct SRS.
- your loaded points don't show up at all, maybe the project SRS doesn't render well lat/lon coordinates; try changing it to 4326 and see if it works now.
- **edit**: as user Fezter noticed, it may be that you flipped lat and lon when importing. Make sure you set lat as **Y** and lon as **X**.

As for configuring your layer as 3857, don't. That's a projected SRS, and those coordinates are in geographic. You should configure your layer to its correct SRS, and let the on-the-fly work its magic if needed.